# if else statement in a for loop inline python

Tags: python

I am running the following code, but I encounter an error:

```
name_map = dict(zip(face_names,
                    [e+'.png' for e in 
                        [face_names[0]+(label.split()[0])]
                            if label=='suit' 
                            elif label != 'suit' face_names
```

my error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

from 'elif' on, it fails.

I want ...if label == 'suit'

```
name_map={'john':'johnsuit.png''}
```

otherwise

```
name_map={'john':'john.png'}
```

Comment: You can't have an `elif` inside a larger expression. It can only stand alone on its own line as a statement.

Comment: You can have `else` tho.

Comment: Do yourself (and other programmers who might need to read your code one da) a favor and write more readable code. Split it into more lines and you surely will find the problem yourself.

Comment: You're trying to use a shorthand if/else statement. Check out the [ternary operators](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) and the way they are used.

Comment: Also the parenthesis are not located as they should In addition to the elif that is not possible in shorthand way.

Comment: 'else ' this also i get  'invaid syntax' error.

Comment: @Torxed In certain contexts, yes. `a if b else c` is legal syntax inside a list comprehension, but not if you put it after the for. `[i if i > 5 else 0 for i in range(10)]` is legal and `[i for i in range(10) if i > 5 else 0]` is not legal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try or instead and always wrap independent boolean terms in brackets. This works:

```
l = [1,2,3]
[x for x in l if (x == 2) or (x == 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_map = dict(zip(face_names,
                    [e+'.png' for e in 
                        [face_names[0]+(label.split()[0])]
                            if label=='suit' 
                            elif label != 'suit' face_names
```

1. You haven't closed *so* many constructors: the `dict` comprehension, the `zip` function, and the list comprehension (2nd argument to `zip`) are all still open.
2. Your ternary operator (in-line `if`) is illegal: look up the syntax; among other things, `elif` is not part of such an expression.

Let's see whether I understand this: if the label is "suit", you want to construct a file name; if not, you simply want to use `face_names` as the file name.  Then let's write that part:

```
[face_names[0] + label.split()[0]] if label == "suit"
    else face_names
```

*That* is your expression as you wrote it.  Within your entire statement, this might become

```
name_map = dict(zip(face_names,
                      [e+'.png' for e in 
                          [ face_names[0] + label.split()[0] ]
                      ] if label == "suit"
                        else face_names
                    )
               )
```

Thus, if the label == "suit", you get a *single* element in the second list; otherwise, that argument is a list of `face_names`, each with ".png" appended.
If this is *not* what you wanted, please update the posting appropriately.

---

Update per OP comments

It *appears* that your issue is whether to add "suit" to the end of each file name.  In this case, the logic is significantly simpler:

```
face_names = ["john"]
label = "suit"

name_map = dict(zip(face_names,
                      [e + ('suit.png' if label=="suit" else ".png")
                          for e in face_names]
                    )
               )

print(name_map)
```

This produces:

```
{'john': 'johnsuit.png'}
```

If I change label to `"not_a_suit"`, we get

```
{'john': 'john.png'}
```

Comment: thank you so much,but i just get 'face_names'  when label is not 'suite'.i want to get face_names.png

Comment: Again, please update your posting with the appropriate details.  I believe that I *have* fixed the problem you posted.  You haven't told us what `face_names` is, what you have for inputs, and what you expect as results.  If you want "face_names.png" otherwise, that's a simple change to the code I gave you.  However, what you posted implies that in the "else" case, `face_names` is a list of things to which you want to append '.png'.

Comment: when label='suit' : name_map={'john':johnsuit.png''} and label != 'suit' : name_map={'john':'john.png'}

Comment: i want to this as my output